# Simple Query returning more than specified

Tags: sql

I have a list of data with numbers ranging from 1-500 - 11-500. I created a query to filter out all but the 2-500's. But I am still seeing 1-500, 2-500, and 3-500. Not sure what is wrong with my query. The query is too simple to screw up?!

Example Query:

```
    SELECT job_no, job_name
    FROM JC_JOB
    WHERE job_no like '2-5%'
```

Actual Query:

```
SELECT  w.wrkordnbr
        , rtrim(w.jcjob) + ' ' + s.name
        , w.centernbr
        , w.status
        , w.servsitenbr
        , w.dept
        , s.address
        , s.city 
FROM    wrkorder w, servicesite s 
WHERE   s.servsitenbr = w.servsitenbr 
AND     status NOT IN(1,2,3,4,5,6) 
AND     s.name LIKE '2-5%
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the data type of job_no? Just wondering as I can't seem to reproduce this (I used `nvarchar` for job_no)

Comment: @bird2920:check this ,even i am not able to replicate this [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/502)`sqlfiddle`

Comment: There must be something else in play here.  Are you using variables or is this hard coded exactly as above?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't believe you. If in fact your data is as you describe, the query should only return anything that starts with `2-5....`

Comment: @Icarus While your comment is correct, try not to be condescending.  Obviously something isn't working for him or he would not have posted the question.  Usually when people post a question they try to simplify it a little, which often hides the problem.  At your rep I would have thought you would know this.

Comment: @K'Leg I did not try to be condescending at all. I don't know why you got that impression but I present my apologies. Often times people, in an effort to reduce noise on the question, omit important parts. I just think that may be the case here.

Comment: @Icarus Thanks to both of you for your replies. I was not offended by the tone of the reply. And yes I was omitting a good portion of the query to keep things simple.

Comment: @Icarus Exactly what I was saying.  Perhaps I misunderstood your tone.  I think it was the "I don't believe you"  statement to me that means you think he is deliberately lying, and I don't think that is the case.  As we both said, he attempted to simplify it and in doing so, omitted something important.

Comment: @bird2920 soooo.....    did you figure it out?  are you going to give us some more information to use?   :)

Comment: @K'Leg I see why you understood it that way. I didn't mean to imply that OP was deliberately lying. In Spanish `No te creo` (`I don't believe you`) is a colloquial way of saying `No, kidding!/Get out of here` or something like that. I was lost in translation.

Comment: ahhh  damn language barriers.  well I am glad we settled that, I like this community and don't like thinking someone is being an ass.  I will have to remember that, next time.

Comment: No one here has been an ass. You guys have all been great. I have been following StackOverflow for a very long time without ever signing up. I have always found great help here from everyone. I have never had to ask my own question before. You all performed beyond my expectations. Thanks again to everyone who participates here.

Comment: Is it possible that you have a semicolon after from clause?  This would explain why the where clause is not being executed.

Comment: What kind of data/values are in w.jcjob?

Comment: As far as I know all the fields use varchar and are roughly the same in what kind of data is placed in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry but I don't believe you. If in fact your data is as you describe, the query should only return anything that starts with 2-5....

```
declare @jobs as table
(job_no varchar(20))

insert into @jobs
values (
'1-500'
),('2-500'),('3-500'),('100-500'),('120-500'),('200-500')


SELECT job_no
    FROM @jobs
    WHERE job_no like '2-5%'
```

Returns:

```
job_no
2-500
```

If your data had job_no `112-500`, for example, and your `Where` clause was this instead `where job_no like '%2-5%'` then it would make sense that it would return something like:

```
job_no
2-500
112-500
```

Comment: select w.wrkordnbr, rtrim(w.jcjob) + ' ' + s.name, w.centernbr, w.status, w.servsitenbr, w.dept, s.address, s.city from wrkorder w, servicesite s where s.servsitenbr = w.servsitenbr and status not in(1,2,3,4,5,6) and s.name like '2-5%'

Comment: hrmmm....  the s.name like '2-5%' clause should remove anything that doesn't fit that bill, irregardless of the rest of the statement.  You're not using brackets so it can't be a case of  (this) or (this and this)

Comment: So back to trying to figure out what is wrong.  I would suggest you try using the most simple statement you can, like your OP, then add the other parts to it, in an attempt to discover the bug.  There must be something wrong but as written I don't see it, and I am afraid I cannot be of anymore assistance on this until you troubleshoot some more or offer more information.

Comment: That is where the confusion is for me. There is no reason for it to return 3-5s or 1-5s but it is.

Comment: Try changing s.name like '2-5%' to  s.name='2-500'  (something that does exist)

Comment: I will be on with that client in 2 hours. I will let you all know what the verdict was after our call. Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: @K'Leg I changed to s.name '2-500' - Still no go. select w.wrkordnbr, rtrim(w.jcjob) + '' + s.name, w.centernbr, w.status, w.servsitenbr, w.dept, s.address, s.city from wrkorder w, servicesite s where s.servsitenbr = w.servsitenbr and status not in (1,2,3,4,5,6) and s.jcjob = '2-500'  order by w.jcjob desc

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
SELECT job_no, job_name
FROM JC_JOB
WHERE job_no BETWEEN ('2-5') and ('2-6')
```

I haven't tried it

Comment: I don't see how that would work, you would get everything but what you want.  This should though    SELECT job_no, job_name FROM JC_JOB WHERE job_no BETWEEN ('2-5') and ('2-6')

Comment: Leandro go ahead and change your answer, I think you were on the right track, you just didn't think it through.  While his original query should work, this should as well and may assist in troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks K'Leg. I just registered today to stackoverflow, why I got a -1?

Comment: Cause someone marked your answer as incorrect but now that you have either accepted my edit or corrected your answer yourself I will bump it up +1, that's the best I can do.  Some people are quick to judge, so make sure your answer is good before offering it.

Comment: I remember that work and that problem, I work by myself for clients of outside now. Thanks. I just noticed my reputation is -6, will have to help to get more again.